# Store a simple int variable to a server on github pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an html file with an int variable that is uploaded to GitHub pages.

When the user clicks a button, the int value is changed by += 1, and the value is displayed with `<p> </p>`.

I am a beginner and want to save the int value to some sort of free server or database so the int variable stays the same across all users. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. Also, add your code as well.

Comment: Firebase has two database options both with free tiers, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) and [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start)

Comment: If you don't want a database plan or not familiar with SQL or its setup, you may try creating an API with a file-based JSON database.

Answer (score 0):

As you appreciate already you need some sort of external database and there are a few options with free tiers such as https://www.mongodb.com/ and https://aws.amazon.com/free/database/ to name two.